# Echo a PHP Session Form on Multiple Pages

Tags: php, forms, session, echo

I have been searching for a few hours now on a way to fix this but I have pulled together my php knowledge to get this very small script to not work. I need to make a form that gets submitted which lands you one page one, then on to page two where that information also needs to be displayed.

Form "name" ---> Page one echo name ----> Page Two echo name

I figured I could store this into a session but this doesn't seem to be working.

Here is what I have so far,

form.php

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="input" action="info.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="name"/> <br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

info.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name0'];
$name0 = $_POST['name'];

?>
<html>
<body>

<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>
<a href="next.php">Next</a>

</body>
</html>
```

next.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name0'];
?>

<html>

<body>

<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I am sure this code is very sloppy but it is all i know. Sorry if the answer is already out there I have looked but maybe I am searching wrong.

Comment: Try to accept the answers if it is working as you are looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

info.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $_GET['name'];
?>
<html>
<body>

<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>
<a href="next.php">Next</a>

</body>
</html>
```

next.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>

<html>

<body>

<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Try this changes and check if it is working as expected.

Comment: This worked after changing method="get" to method="post" thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

form.php Here you use GET:

```
<form name="input" action="info.php" method="get">
```

info.php Here you assigned the session variable to a post value (im not even sure where name0 came from):

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name0'];  
$name0 = $_POST['name'];
```

next.php Here you assigned the session variable to the same post value (inexistant):

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name0'];
```

Change your code to this:

info.php

```
<?php            
    session_start();           
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_GET['name'];           
    $name0 = $_POST['name'];                 
?>           
<html>           
    <body>                   
        <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>           
        <a href="next.php">Next</a>                     
    </body>           
</html>
```

next.php

```
<?php               
    session_start();                          
?>              

<html>                           
    <body>                  
        <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>              
    </body>              
</html>
```